# No bin directory in Erlang installation directory on Windows Server 2019 SE

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, erlang

Have you experienced the situation mentioned in question title?
My Erlang (23.1) installation directory looks like below, bin directory is missing.

[image: erl-23.1]

Because of it I am not able to use RabbitMQ. Another weird thing is that I've installed on another OS exactly the same version, even using exactly the same installer file. Any ideas?

Comment: @the_one_who_minused
What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Case closed, I am not pretty sure about the reason, but when I logged in using another account and installed Erlang again, the bin directory has appeared. Server owner checked that my account and that another one both have admin rights. I have no option to verify that, but I suspect that not everything was ok with those admin permissions.